# Parameters of gaussian distribution, which is generated using central limit theorem

Tags: javascript, random, normal-distribution

In a software I am working on (sensor simulation), I needed to generate normally distributed noise for simulated sensor signals. I used the central limit theorem. I generated 20 random numbers and built an average out of them to approximate the gaussian distribution.

So I took the "measured" signal and generated 20 numbers from **`-noiseMax`** to **`+noiseMax`** and averaged them. I added the result to the signal to have noise.

Now, for my university, I have to describe this Gaussian distribution by its **mean** and **variance**. Ok, **mean** will be **0** but I have absolutely no idea how to convert **noiseMax** in my program into the variance. Googling haven't helped much.

I was not sure if SO is the right SE platform for this question. Sorry if it isn't.

Comment: The question may have been better received on statistics.stackexchange, but I think it's within scope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the central limit theorem says that the average of a sufficiently large number of uniformally distributed variables will be normal. In the statistics classes I have taken, 30 is usually used as the cutoff, so you might want to increase your simulation's "sample size".

However, you can find the Standard Deviation of your average as follows regardless of "sample size".

The standard deviation of your uniform variable is [`(b-a)/sqrt(12)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29)`== noiseMax/sqrt(3)`.

Variances add when you add variables, so the standard deviation of `n` the sum of `n` of these variables is `sqrt(n*(noiseMax/sqrt(3))*(noiseMax/sqrt(3)))==noiseMax*sqrt(n/3)`.

Dividing by `n` to get the average gives you a final standard deviation of `noiseMax/sqrt(3*n)`. In your case, `sigma = noiseMax * 0.12909944487`.

Answer (score 1):

From theoretical POV this is known as Irwin-Hall distribution

Simplest to produce N(0,1) is sum of 12 uniform RN minus 6, no need for scaling

In general, to see how variance is computed, take a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

I would also recommend to look at the Table of Numerical Values in the following article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule.

For example, if one to use sum of 12 uniform numbers (minus 6), then min value would be at -6 (exactly -6*sigma) and max value would be at +6 (exactly +6*sigma). Looking at the table, what would be expected frequency outside the range? Answer: 1/506797346. Thus, one out of ~half a billion events shall land outside the +-6sigma, but Irwill-Hall(12) rng will miss it. Thus, you could judge if it is ok or not for your particular simulation

Comment: Gave you plus 1 for mentioning the Irwin-Hall-Distribution. But the answer of @k_g contains the ready formula I've been looking for - that's why I've accepted his answer.